# The text inside my HTML button goes outside the button

Tags: html, css, button, padding

I have a 'Download' button on my HTML webpage and I have set some attributes for it.

Whenever I refresh my page, the button appears like this, very rarely:

Text Outside the Button

[image]

But then, it will look like this and this is the normal-looking button:

Normal Button

[image]

```css
.navbar-download-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  top: 5.7%;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2.2px solid white;
  padding: 0.8%;
  border-radius: 3.5px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: Noto Sans KR, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#Download"><button class="navbar-download-btn nonindex">Download</button></a>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODSE, not just pictures. "I have set some attributes"  - we cannot guess what you did there

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Your class is `navbar-download-btn-nonindex` but your CSS does `navbar-download-btn`

Comment: I have 2 'Download' buttons but the problem is with the CSS.

Comment: Please fix the snippet I made you to show the actual issue. Transparent and white does not show here. I made it blue

Comment: Add a width rule `width:8rem`, should be it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a problem in the padding of the download button, Increase the padding from the right and also try running this code in other browsers, this had been a problem for me too earlier but sometimes it could just be your browser...

Answer (score -1):

```css
text-align: center;
margin-right:
```

Comment: Please give more context in your answers, explaining what they do,

Comment: Try set the text-align to center and the margin-right to 10px